# Lagrangian interpolating polynomial code outputing an incorrect answer in matlab

Tags: summation, matlab, interpolation, products, lagrange-interpolation

I have to write code in matlab for a lagrangian interpolating polynomial that intakes some set of x and y values and a desired x value (named 'c' here) to be estimated and outputs the interpolating polynomial's value at 'c' in matlab

here is the code that I wrote:

```
function polyatc = lagrange(Xlist, Ylist, c)
    polyatc = 0;
    xprod=1;
    for i=1:size(Ylist)
        for j= setdiff(1:size(Xlist), i)
            xprod=xprod*((c-Xlist(j))/(Xlist(i)-Xlist(j)));
        end
        polyatc = polyatc+Ylist(i)*xprod;
    end
    disp(polyatc);
end
```

where polyatc should be the sum of all the y parts of the polynomial estimation for the function value at point x=c and xprod should be the product part of $f(x)*\frac{((x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i+1})...(x-x_n))}{((x_i-x_1)(x_i-x_2)...(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i+1})...(x_i-x_n))}$

This all looks right to me and looks very similar to ones I have found online, however, when I input lagrange([1,5],[3,11],2) I get 3 when I should get 5 as the subsequent interpolating polynomial is 2x+1. I've tried following the logic of the code but I always come out with 5 and can't figure out where it is going wrong.

This is all being done on MATLAB R2019a for academic use.

Comment: General hint: something like this is easy enough to do by hand that you can write out what you expect the code to produce, and then use the debugger (if you don't know how, learn right now!) to compare what happens to what you expect. But the time you'd gotten to the very first iteration of the first loop you'd find out that your upper index in the second loop was broken, and by the second iteration of the outer loop, you'd discover your initialization of xprod was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- *xprod = 1* should be inside the first loop;
- use *1:length(...)* for the length of your array (because *1:setdiff(1:size(Xlist), 1)* yields the empty array).